# phpEXCEL getCalculatedValue not returning desired results

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have tried using the debug tool posted in reply to similar questions but was unable to find a solution to my problem. My excel sheet looks as follows:
G36 = SUM(G24:G28). G24->G28 = SUM(B24:G24) and so on.

It returns formula with getValue() and #Value with getCalculatedValue()

Following is the output of the debug tool.

> Formula Value is=SUM(G28:G34) Expected Value is UNKNOWN Parser Stack
>   :- Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value] => G28
>   [reference] => G28 ) [1] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value]
>   => G34 [reference] => G34 ) [2] => Array ( [type] => Binary Operator [value] => : [reference] => ) [3] => Array ( [type] => Operand Count
>   for Function SUM() [value] => 1 [reference] => ) [4] => Array ( [type]
>   => Function [value] => SUM( [reference] => ) ) Calculated Value is 0 Evaluation Log: Array ( [0] => Testing cache value for cell
>   Worksheet!G36 [1] => Retrieving value for cell Worksheet!G36 from
>   cache )

```
function testFormula($sheet,$cell) {
$formulaValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getValue();
echo 'Formula Value is' , $formulaValue , PHP_EOL;
$expectedValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getOldCalculatedValue();
echo 'Expected Value is '  , ((!is_null($expectedValue)) ? $expectedValue : 'UNKNOWN') , PHP_EOL;


$calculate = false;
try {
    $tokens = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
        $sheet->getParent()
    )->parseFormula(
        $formulaValue,
        $sheet->getCell($cell)
    );
    echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
    print_r($tokens);
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $calculate = true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'PARSER ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

    echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
    print_r($tokens);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

if ($calculate) {
    PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
        $sheet->getParent()
    )->getDebugLog()
    ->setWriteDebugLog(true);
    try {
        $cellValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
        echo 'Calculated Value is ' , $cellValue , PHP_EOL;

        echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r(
            PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
                $sheet->getParent()
            )->getDebugLog()
            ->getLog()
        );
        echo PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

        echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r(
            PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
                $sheet->getParent()
            )->debugLog
            ->getLog()
        );
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
}


    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    testFormula($sheet,'G36');
```

Following is the output after I implemented the changes recommended by @MarkBaker in his answer below.

> Formula Value is=SUM(G28:G34) Expected Value is UNKNOWN Parser Stack
>   :- Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value] => G28
>   [reference] => G28 ) [1] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value]
>   => G34 [reference] => G34 ) [2] => Array ( [type] => Binary Operator [value] => : [reference] => ) [3] => Array ( [type] => Operand Count
>   for Function SUM() [value] => 1 [reference] => ) [4] => Array ( [type]
>   => Function [value] => SUM( [reference] => ) ) Calculated Value is 0 Evaluation Log: Array ( [0] => Testing cache value for cell
>   Worksheet!G36 [1] => Worksheet!G36 => Evaluating Cell G28 in current
>   worksheet [2] => Worksheet!G36 => Testing cache value for cell
>   Worksheet!G28 [3] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 => Evaluating Cell
>   D28 in current worksheet [4] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 =>
>   Testing cache value for cell Worksheet!D28 [5] => Worksheet!G36 ->
>   Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!D28 => Evaluating Cell B28 in current
>   worksheet [6] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!D28 =>
>   Evaluation Result for cell Worksheet!B28 is a floating point number
>   with a value of 10000 [7] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 ->
>   Worksheet!D28 => Evaluating Cell C28 in current worksheet [8] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!D28 => Evaluation Result
>   for cell Worksheet!C28 is a floating point number with a value of 140
>   [9] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!D28 => Evaluating
>   10000 * 140 [10] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!D28 =>
>   Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 1400000
>   [11] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 => Evaluation Result for cell
>   Worksheet!D28 is a floating point number with a value of 1400000 [12]
>   => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 => Evaluating Cell F28 in current worksheet [13] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 => Testing cache
>   value for cell Worksheet!F28 [14] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 ->
>   Worksheet!F28 => Evaluating Cell D28 in current worksheet [15] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!F28 => Testing cache value
>   for cell Worksheet!D28 [16] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 ->
>   Worksheet!F28 => Retrieving value for cell Worksheet!D28 from cache
>   [17] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!F28 => Evaluation
>   Result for cell Worksheet!D28 is a floating point number with a value
>   of 1400000 [18] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!F28 =>
>   Evaluating Cell E28 in current worksheet [19] => Worksheet!G36 ->
>   Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!F28 => Evaluation Result for cell
>   Worksheet!E28 is a string with a value of "3%" [20] => Worksheet!G36
>   -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!F28 => Evaluating 1400000 * "3%" [21] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 -> Worksheet!F28 => Evaluation Result
>   is a a #VALUE! error [22] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 =>
>   Evaluation Result for cell Worksheet!F28 is a #VALUE! error [23] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 => Evaluating 1400000 + "#VALUE!" [24]
>   => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G28 => Evaluation Result is a #VALUE! error [25] => Worksheet!G36 => Evaluation Result for cell
>   Worksheet!G28 is a #VALUE! error [26] => Worksheet!G36 => Evaluating
>   Cell G34 in current worksheet [27] => Worksheet!G36 => Evaluation
>   Result for cell Worksheet!G34 is a NULL value [28] => Worksheet!G36 =>
>   Evaluating Range "Worksheet!G28" : "Worksheet!G34" [29] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 => Testing cache value for cell Worksheet!G28 [30] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 => Retrieving value for cell Worksheet!G28 from cache
>   [31] => Worksheet!G36 => Testing cache value for cell Worksheet!G29
>   [32] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 => Evaluating Cell D29 in
>   current worksheet [33] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 => Testing
>   cache value for cell Worksheet!D29 [34] => Worksheet!G36 ->
>   Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!D29 => Evaluating Cell B29 in current
>   worksheet [35] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!D29 =>
>   Evaluation Result for cell Worksheet!B29 is a floating point number
>   with a value of 5000 [36] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 ->
>   Worksheet!D29 => Evaluating Cell C29 in current worksheet [37] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!D29 => Evaluation Result
>   for cell Worksheet!C29 is a floating point number with a value of 102
>   [38] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!D29 => Evaluating
>   5000 * 102 [39] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!D29 =>
>   Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 510000
>   [40] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 => Evaluation Result for cell
>   Worksheet!D29 is a floating point number with a value of 510000 [41]
>   => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 => Evaluating Cell F29 in current worksheet [42] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 => Testing cache
>   value for cell Worksheet!F29 [43] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 ->
>   Worksheet!F29 => Evaluating Cell D29 in current worksheet [44] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!F29 => Testing cache value
>   for cell Worksheet!D29 [45] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 ->
>   Worksheet!F29 => Retrieving value for cell Worksheet!D29 from cache
>   [46] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!F29 => Evaluation
>   Result for cell Worksheet!D29 is a floating point number with a value
>   of 510000 [47] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!F29 =>
>   Evaluating Cell E29 in current worksheet [48] => Worksheet!G36 ->
>   Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!F29 => Evaluation Result for cell
>   Worksheet!E29 is a string with a value of "3%" [49] => Worksheet!G36
>   -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!F29 => Evaluating 510000 * "3%" [50] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 -> Worksheet!F29 => Evaluation Result
>   is a a #VALUE! error [51] => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 =>
>   Evaluation Result for cell Worksheet!F29 is a #VALUE! error [52] =>
>   Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 => Evaluating 510000 + "#VALUE!" [53]
>   => Worksheet!G36 -> Worksheet!G29 => Evaluation Result is a #VALUE! error [54] => Worksheet!G36 => Evaluating Function SUM() with 1
>   argument [55] => Worksheet!G36 => Evaluating SUM( { "#VALUE!";
>   "#VALUE!"; ; ; ; ; } ) [56] => Worksheet!G36 => Evaluation Result for
>   SUM() function call is an integer number with a value of 0 ) 14:16:49
>   Write to Excel2007 format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation entry `Retrieving value for cell Worksheet!G36 from cache` tells you that the calculation engine is retrieving the data from a previous request to `getCalculatedValue()` that has been cached.

Perhaps you should try flushing the calculation cache and then rerunning the calculation through the logger.

You can flush the calculation cache using

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
    $objPHPExcel
)->flushInstance();
```

then you will be able to recalculate the formula in its entirety, and see how the calculation is being performed

**EDIT**

To set a cell containing a percentage value using PHPExcel do:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell("E$a")
    ->setValue($taxrate / 100);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell("E$a")
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE);
```

For a `$taxrate` value of `3`, this will store `0.03` in the cell, but display it as `3%`. 0.03 is the correct value to use in the formula expression.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. I am new to this and not sure where to put this flush Instance. I tried this at the top of the function but didn't quite work. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: If you put it inside the function, you'll need to put it before the call to `getCalculatedValue()` and you'll need to modify it to `PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
    $sheet->getParent()

)->flushInstance();`

Comment: Ok well it gets lost after it tries to get output as a result of a number multiplied with 3%. I assume this happened because it is considering 3% as  a String. I tried changing format but that didn't help either. 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F28:F36')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#0% ');

I also tried to set it to percentage format by using following code:
setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00);

Comment: If you have a cell that contains `3%` as a string, then this will potentially equate to `3` in a formula (depends on exactly how it is used), but at best the result is unpredictable; if the cell contains `0.03` with a `%` number format mask, then you will get a different result.

Comment: Percentages should always be stored in Excel using a format mask rather than as a string containing the `%` sign, otherwise MS Excel itself will be unable to parse them correctly in a formula

Comment: Oh thank you for your help. it worked. I changed it to 0.03 and applied format using setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00);